# Unable To Hook NtCreateFile

Tags: visual-c++, api-hook

I am Hooking to NtCreateFile Function but i am not because of some errors. my code is
as below .am getting two errors that are 
1)unresolved external symbol _NtCreateFile and 
2)1 unresolved externals .
please help me .

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MinHook.h"
#include <Winternl.h>

#if defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(lib, "libMinHook.x64.lib")
#elif defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(lib, "libMinHook.x86.lib")
#endif

typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI *NtCreateFileNext)(PHANDLE FileHandle,ACCESS_MASK    DesiredAccess,POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
                                    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,PLARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize,ULONG FileAttributes,
                                    ULONG ShareAccess,ULONG CreateDisposition,ULONG CreateOptions,PVOID EaBuffer,ULONG EaLength);

NtCreateFileNext Real_NtCreateFileData = NULL;

NTSTATUS WINAPI NtCreateFileCallback(PHANDLE FileHandle,ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
                                    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,PLARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize,ULONG FileAttributes,
                                    ULONG ShareAccess,ULONG CreateDisposition,ULONG CreateOptions,PVOID EaBuffer,ULONG EaLength)
{

 MessageBoxA(NULL,"NtCreateFile Called","Info",MB_OK);
 return(FileHandle, DesiredAccess, ObjectAttributes,IoStatusBlock, AllocationSize, FileAttributes,
        ShareAccess, CreateDisposition, CreateOptions, EaBuffer, EaLength);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,LPVOID lpReserved)
{
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
                        if (MH_CreateHook(&NtCreateFile, &NtCreateFileCallback, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&Real_NtCreateFileData)) != MH_OK)
                        {
                            MessageBoxW(NULL,L"Failed CreateHook NtCreateFile",L"Info!",MB_ICONWARNING|MB_OK);
                        }
                        if (MH_EnableHook(&NtCreateFile) != MH_OK)
                        {
                            MessageBoxW(NULL,L"Failed EnableHook NtCreateFile",L"Info!",MB_ICONWARNING|MB_OK);
                        }
                        break;

case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
                        if (MH_Uninitialize() != MH_OK)
                        {               
                        }
                        if (MH_DisableHook(&NtCreateFile) != MH_OK)
                        {
                        }
                        break;
}
return TRUE;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Kantesh: you need to get the windows driver kit and include NtDll.lib as additional dependency in the linker/input property page.. HTH's